# "Авось" и "небось"

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы еще понять происхождение слов "авось" и "небось".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Авось < А+ось, Небось < Не (было) ось.
Ось - архаичная указательная частица, со знаением "вот", "это", "оно самое". "Ось тебе раз!" - такое ещё недавно можно было услышать в деревнях. С небось немного посложнее, там еще более хитрая фонетическая замена, но смысл тот же.

См. ещё вопрос про "авоську".

Comment: А как указательная частица связана со смыслом слова (особенно авось)?

Comment: Так оно, вроде, самодостаточно как объяснение.
"А вот и будет" -  "А вот и не будет"! = "Авось будет" - "Небось не будет". Как-то так.

Answer (score 1):

авось  от --а бы есть, небось  от -- не боись. НЕ ось  тебе  есть, а оть, тебе.  с глотанием первой  буквы,именно так в деревнях псковщины и новгородчины.
минусы без обсуждения---троллинг, мягко сказано.

Ось в малороссийском  "ось, глянь"   обязательно с глаголом,  "на кось, смотри" русский аналог,   накося выкуси в русском, про частицу и фасмеровскую этимологию:

авось аво́сь нареч., др.-русск. авосе (Лаврентьевск.), осе "вот"; часто в XII – XIV вв.; укр. аво́, аво́сь "гляди, глянь". Из а+осе с вторичн. в (Соболевский, Лекции 95). Менее вероятно объяснение из *а-ово-се (Зубатый, LF 36, 112 и сл.; 341; Потебня у Горяева, ЭС 1 и Преобр. 1, 1). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Нако ся, вот это будет верно, с подразумевающимся -- се, те, тебе, сам.
Но с авось это никак логически не связано, а логика вероятности, "а бы есть"  с заменой произношения с твердого Б на мягкое в.  абы да кабы.
а еще есть слово овесень-авсень, до весны дожить, абы есть было что, вот и получилось авось.
Овсы--тоже связано. Корм лошадиный, для человека не питательный, только с голодухи. Весной подъедали, да кисель варили, небось(не боись) дотянем.

Comment: >Ось в малороссийском "ось, глянь" обязательно с глаголом

Почему "обязательно"? Совсем не обязательно.

.

*"Ось"* (вот) или более разговорный, чем литературный, вариант *"осьО"* (вот тут), как угодно можно употреблять. В том числе и как единственное слово во фразе.

Не хочу перегружать сообщение  непонятными примерами. Поэтому напишу вопрос по-русски.

-- Где эта вещь?  
-- Осьо!

Comment: Это где это вы слышали такое, в России.?
"Осьо рівняння откао сьово множимо на осьдо..." встал и вышел, несмотря, что был главой комиссии.
А вот в Житомире суржик--это да. Бабуся говорит: "Осьо и у мэнэ.. . Як не задалося жытття, так и не пийшло... "
или еще:  Он опять подойдёт -"Осьсьо було не тако ,а зараз тепер отако "  Доцент причём.

Answer (score -1):

Если копнуть близкородственный санскрит, 
то **"avas"** - способствование осуществлению, защита, помощь, желание
**"avasara"** - шанс
http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=avas&direct=se&anz=all

**"Небось"** - возможно, от "небеса" (**"nabhasa"** в санскрите), со значением "высшие силы"
http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=nabhasa&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3

Comment: А как эти слова связаны с русскими?

Comment: Ну вообще-то русский язык чрезвычайно сильно пересекается с индоевропейской частью санскрита. Факт достаточно известный, но который ненавидят лингвисты, отделываясь словами об "общем индоевропейском происхождении" и "замедленном развитии русского языка".